# Loading static files in template

Tags: django

I am pretty new to Django and I am trying to put static files in my site but I am unable to do so. I am getting 404 when the browser tries to GET my static files

I'm not sure of the best practices or the correct way for Django to find these static files

Here is a picture of my project structure:

[image]

Here is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

In my index.html I have a line:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}boothie.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}boothie.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery.js.1.3.js"></script>
```

Comment: And the `DUBUG` status is ?

Comment: @rajasimon new ot Django not really sure how to debug at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href="{% static "css/boothie.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static "js/boothie.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.js.1.3.js" %}"></script>
```

See: [Configuring static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Edit:

You can maintain static files which belong to your `home` app with the structure like this:

```
home/
    static/
        css/
        images/
        js/
```

While deploying, you can set `STATIC_ROOT` to where you want to serve these static files, then run `python manage.py collectstatic`, django will copy your static files into the `STATIC_ROOT` directory and you can maintain static files easier (in a single directory) without changing your code.

Comment: I tried the same concept for images but it doesnt work =/ However this did fi my CSS and JS problems

Comment: From your snapshot, it seems that your Boothie/static/images directory is empty; try `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: I got it to work actually. There are images in my `home` directory so what I did was `<img src="{% static "home/images/ming.jpg" %}" ` Not sure if this is best practices though =/

Comment: @Liondancer -- Edited my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

`static_url` will give the relative path ....

You may have to include

```
<link href="{% static "css/boothie.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I think you have an additional `/` in your path

Comment: @dazedconfused confused when typo ...!